# Moisture sensor gives weird results when connected to a relay

Tags: pi-3, python, relay, wiring

I was about to review the items as faulty when I connected my brain and made a second test.
The sensor is supposed to return 0 when dry and 1 when wet. In my script I repeat the reading 100 times. I get exactly 100 zeroes or ones depending on the situation. So the sensor is not faulty.
Now, I don't want to keep the sensor always powered. It corrodes due to electrolisis. So I'm powering the sensor once per hour using a relay.

The script triggers the relay, the sensor switches on, I wait 5 seconds (probably not needed), then I read the digital value 100 times.
Result (the sequence of 0s and 1s is different every time but always in groups of 10 or more, so not 0-1-0-1-1-0)
[image]

I suspected some non-constant current flow, so I tested the wiring. The output is 5V both from the raspberry and from the external source (measured at the sensor pins).

I'm not an electronic expert (disclaimer :-) ) the only thing I see is that the wire that brings the return signal from the sensor is not on the same circuit as the power supply. Does it make sense? There are no resistors in my circuit.

What can it be to cause this anomaly?

The sensor is this one

[image]

Comment: try connecting both grounds together.

Comment: You need to give a circuit diagram showing the  electrical connections between  Pi, sensor, relay, and  power supplies.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobillard - That was the problem. Not the first time I make this mistake